# Why does this always evaluate false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

I'm working on some jQuery to resize images on a page. This block works fine:

```
var size = 350;
$("img").each(function () {
    if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
        var h = size;
        var w = Math.ceil(($(this).width() / $(this).height()) * size);
    }
    else {
        var w = size;
        var h = Math.ceil(($(this).height() / $(this).width()) * size);
    }
    $(this).css({ "height": h, "width": w });
});
```

The problem is small images are scaled up. No problem, one more if statement should take care of that!

```
var size = 350;
$("img").each(function () {
    if ($(this).height() > size || $(this).width() > size) { //Always false
        if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
            var h = size;
            var w = Math.ceil(($(this).width() / $(this).height()) * size);
        }
        else {
            var w = size;
            var h = Math.ceil(($(this).height() / $(this).width()) * size);
        }
        $(this).css({ "height": h, "width": w });
    }
});
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What are the sizes (height/width) of your images?

Comment: Did you try to `alert()` the values? Maybe they are `null`?

Comment: The images come in all sorts of sizes. The source is a crawl of stared messages in chat.stackoverflow.com; so whatever people post.

Comment: If the images are still loading, their dimensions will be `0`. Are you running this immediately when the DOM is ready?

Comment: Interesting, it's only throwing the value of the img tag, not the source. I think You found the problem @Chamster.

Comment: @user1689607 That was exactly it. I changed it from .each to .load and wham, fixed!

Comment: Quote: Caveats of the `load` event when used with images: Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). You'd better use __both__ `each` and `load` (if you don't mind running the code twice).

Comment: @Billdr: Abstract chat.stackoverflow.com away from the problem as it is completely not relevant. Make a testcase with some sample image that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Billdr So why don't you check my reply as green (but no upvote, please - I'm aiming for Unsung Hero, haha).

Comment: @Chamster Sorry, saw the answer before this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be that you **think** you're getting values from a component, while you're in fact getting value (or not getting any values other than `null`) from **somewhere else**.

A quick and dirty approach is to:

```javascript
alert(thatDarnedValue);
```

or, if you know how, write it out to the console window, development DIV or whatever you use to debug and **actually see** what's in there.

I often get surprised - "**this** is **not** supposed to be there"-experience.

This kind of pitfall is often the case when we're checking for values of graphical components at different stages of readiness. A document might be loaded but not ready etc.

Comment: @Billdr Why the down vote?! I thought you were **helped** by my suggestion... Do I miss something?

Comment: That wasn't from me. I'll get you back to 0.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was my script was firing before the images on my page loaded, even though the script tag was at the bottom of the page. Lesson learned there! I changed the .each to a .load, which is fine for my purposes.

A better solution might be to wrap this in the `$("window").load()` event or `$(document).ready()`.